# Julia - Transferring data between workers

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, distributed-computing

Let's say that we have defined two workers in Julia. I am wondering if it is possible to send data computed in worker 3, directly to worker 2 without fetching data in master process and sending it to worker 2, afterwards? In general, with the existing parallel tools in Julia i.e. @spawn, fetch and etc, is it possible that one worker gets data (messages) from different workers and use them in order to compute a message for another worker?

Note: I know that there is a MPI wrapper which may be more compatible with this issue, however still I am wondering if this can be done with the existing parallel tools in Julia? In other words, when they say that message passing in Julia is “one-sided”, does it mean that transferring data between workers is not feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [ParallelDataTransfer.jl](https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/ParallelDataTransfer.jl), just do

```
# Get an object from named x from Main module on process 2. Name it y
y = @getfrom 2 x
```

and see the README for more examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I started using the mentioned package, however still I have some issues: 1- How to perform a computation on a worker using its own local variables? For example, let's define "x=pi" on process 2 using "sendto(2,x=pi)", now how to execute the function "sin(x)" on process 2 and put the result in variable "y" which also lives in process 2?

Comment: use `spawnat` or other parallel calls.

Comment: 2- Following question 1, is it possible that a worker (say i) request a function to be executed on another worker (say j), using worker j's own local variables and then fetch the result on worker i? For instance in the above example, how can process 3 request process 2 to compute "sin(x)" where "x" lives in process 2, and then send the result to variable "z" which lives in process 3?

Comment: You'll want to ask another question if you want a good explanation with examples.

Comment: the point is using either of "@spawnat 2 y=sin(x)" or "y=@spawnat 2 sin(x)" does not put the result in variable "y" which is supposed to live in process 2. This can seen by running "@spawnat 2 whos()" where the variable "y" doesn't appear.

Comment: Yeah, and an answer is worthy of another question. I don't know how to do this off the top of my head, but doing it as another SO question will invite others to answer.